# Building multidimensional array with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to loop though my items, build a multidimensional array and send it to another page in the following format

`item[22] = [2,4,55] 
 item[56] = [54,33,535]`

My HTML structure looks somewhat like this:

```
<div data-item="22" class="item">
    <div data-val="2"></div>
    <div data-val="4"></div>
    <div data-val="55"></div>
</div>
<div data-item="56" class="item">
    <div data-val="54"></div>
    <div data-val="33"></div>
    <div data-val="535"></div>
</div>
```

My ajax looks somewhat like this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url:  '/ajax.php',
   data: {
     'item': myArray
   },
   dataType : 'json',
   async: true
...
```

I suppose I could start by doing something like this:

```
myArray= [];

$('.item').each(function(){
    var itemID = $(this).attr('data-item'),
        itemVal = ???;
    myArray.push([itemID , itemVal]);
});
```

However, I'm not sure how to string together the values. Do I run a separate look for each item?

Comment: Instead of multidimensional array with hundreds of holes, `Object` will be better choice

Comment: @Tushar I'm open to this suggestion. Is your suggestion similar to what guest271314 provided below? I can't seem to be able to see results though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to iterate over each `data-val` element.

```js
myArray = [];
$('.item').each(function() {
  myArray[$(this).attr('data-item')] = $(this).find('[data-val]').map(function() {
    return $(this).data('val')
  }).get();
});

snippet.log(JSON.stringify(myArray))
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-item="22" class="item">
  <div data-val="2"></div>
  <div data-val="4"></div>
  <div data-val="55"></div>
</div>
<div data-item="56" class="item">
  <div data-val="54"></div>
  <div data-val="33"></div>
  <div data-val="535"></div>
</div>
```

Also, I think you might want to use `myArray` as an key-value object, not as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Like this!

```
myArray= [];

$('.item').each(function() {
  myArray[$(this).attr('data-item')] = $(this).find('div').map(function() {
    return $(this).data('val')
  }).get();
});

console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$.each()` , `$.map()` to iterate `.item` , set property of object to `.item` `data-item` , with value array of `.item` children `data-val`

```js
var item = {};
$.each($(".item"), function(index, el) {  
  item[Number($(el).data().item)] = $.map(el.children, function(elem, i) {
    return Number($(elem).data().val)
  });
  
});

console.log(item[22], item[56])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div data-item="22" class="item">
    <div data-val="2"></div>
    <div data-val="4"></div>
    <div data-val="55"></div>
</div>
<div data-item="56" class="item">
    <div data-val="54"></div>
    <div data-val="33"></div>
    <div data-val="535"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @santa Object returned with properties `22` , `56` . `el` are `.item` elements , `elem` are `el` children having `data-val` attributes